# Load only the first video chunk for a stream from Brightcove

Tags: ios, avfoundation, brightcove

I want to preload the video for users, but I don't want to waste bandwidth by preloading too much, in case they don't end up watching it. How can I load the only the first chunk from a .m3u8 video stream, using my own loading logic? `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` would be perfect, but I don't see how to leverage it without some visibility into Brightcove's stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing KVO on the Brightcove controller with keypath `currentSession.player.currentItem` and then whenever Brightcove tried to change that, I would take whatever URL it was using, create a new asset with that URL, and swap that one in. Just trying to change the delegate of the existing resourceLoader, however, will not work.